# Error during creating ispac file from integration services project on CI machine

Tags: ssis, msbuild

I have Visual Studio 2012 solution with integration services project. This project contains ssis package. I want to create ispac file for my SSIS to do it I utilize 
DeploymentFileCompilerTask task from [Microsoft SQL Server Community Samples: Integration Services](http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/) but I get the following error:

> error MSB4062: The "DeploymentFileCompilerTask" task could not be
>   loaded from the assembly
>   C:\abc\deployment\tools\SSISMSBuild\Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Build.dll.
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS,
>   Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Confirm that the  declaration is correct, tha  the assembly
>   and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a
>   public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

I execute DeploymentFileCompilerTask using msbuild script which works well on developer machine, but when I'm trying to execute it on agent (continous integration) machine I got above error.
What should I install on this machine? Is it required to install Sql Server 2012? Is any other way to generate ispac file?

Comment: You'll need to install SSDT I suppose... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500335(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: I did it, nothing changed ;/

Comment: I found information that I have to install Sql Server Client Tools SDK. But I can't find setup file for this component and I can't mount sql server on agent machine.

Comment: It is on the SQL Server developer ISO. If needed you can extract the ISO, and there are separate MSI's in the `[ISO]F:\x64\Setup` folder. Not sure if you can just run those though...

Comment: The SSDT you installed- is it a 555KB file or a 800MB file?

Comment: billinkc I installed 555KB version available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650015

Comment: I haven't found any sollution to do it. So we installed entire sql server on jenkins agent.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to to post an answer here as I could not find *any* guidance online for build server pre-requisites and have been experimenting.

I found that the 'Sql Server Client Tools SDK' feature did provide enough assemblies to compile a SSIS project to an ISPAC file without installing SQL Server Database Engine or SSIS.

Here's the list of features that I am providing to SQL Server's command line installation (powershell snippet):

- -CompleteManagement $true
- -Sdk $true
- -SqlServerDataTools $true

Consult the Microsoft [SQL Server Command Line Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) for all of the supported features. They are somewhat granular and allow you to customize your installation.

Notes:

- I am using the code samples provided at this blog post to build an SSIS project to ISPAC via MSBuild: [Building SSIS 2012 using MSBuild – A Journey to DB deployment automation](http://speaksql.wordpress.com/2013/06/07/a-journey-to-db-deployment-automaton-ssis-build-using-msbuild/)
- SSDT has gone through a number of updates since the SQL Server 2012 release, you will probably need an updated standalone installer of SSDT if you are also looking to compile a database project as well

Hope this helps someone else if not the original poster -